# How do I restore Desktop to my favorites list in Finder?

Tags: macbook-pro

I know to drag the icon. But I don't know where the Desktop is to be found to drag! It's probably a simple thing...but I don't know where it is! Duh!

Answer (score 8):

Use Finder Prefs -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>,</kbd>  & check the box next to Desktop

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use ⌘-Shift-G in finder, then go to "~" (without quotes". You can drag Desktop to the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Desktop is kept in your home (user) directory. Normally when you click the Finder icon in the Dock it'll take you straight there to your users home, if not it'll (normally) be in the Favorites bar already, so open it up.

Then you can just drag Desktop over to the Favorites.

Alternatively, you can use the Go menu in Finder, or ⌘-Shift-D to get it up, then, just drag the folder icon from the title bar of the window itself over to the Favorites bar.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Finder** > **Preferences** > **Sidebar**

[image]

Check the options, you want to have. In this case, **Desktop**.

[image]